# Google Play App Rejected for violating dangerous products policy

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I have been trying to publish my application that i developed using cordova tools for VS 2013, and i keep on getting my application was rejected for violating dangerous products policy.

I searched around trying to get a solution but with no luck. I ran this

```
command(cordova -v)
```

to check which version of cordova i am using and i found out that it is 4.2.0, i put this line

```
(**<preference name="phonegap-version" value="4.2.0" />**)
```

inside my config.xml but no luck.

Can someone please explain to me what i might not be doing right.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building using PhoneGap?  If so, be sure to use Cordova version 4.3.1 or higher.  There's a known Android security flaw that was heavily reported when it was found. The latest VS 2013 Tools for Apache Cordova update should already be using a version higher than this version as is VS 2015.

See [this article for remediation steps](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-android-security-05-26-2015-readme/).